# Is "[..., :3]" other way of doing "append" in <"imgs = [plt.imread(fname)[...,:3] for fname in filenames]" >

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to read 100 images into filenames[:100],and for every image
(1) crop
(2) Resize to 100 x 100

Convert all these images into np array.
and plot a montage of that.
[image]

I am quite new to python, please let me know if "plt.imread(fname)[...,3]" is nothing but appending.

thanks.

EDIT:
I want to create montage of 100 specific pictures.
so my code will be something like this:-

```
import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage.transform import resize

dirname = "Images/n02087046-toy_terrier"

filenames = [os.path.join(dirname, fname)
             for fname in os.listdir(dirname)
             if '.jpg' in fname]

filenames = filenames[:100]
assert(len(filenames) == 100)
# Read every filename as an RGB image
imgs = [plt.imread(fname)[...,:3] for fname in filenames]

# Crop
imgs = [utils.imcrop_tosquare(img_i) for img_i in imgs]

# Then resize the square image to 100 x 100 pixels
imgs = [resize(img_i, (100, 100)) for img_i in imgs]

imgs = np.array(imgs).astype(np.float32)

imgs.shape

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))

#montage is a utility function.
plt.imshow(utils.montage(imgs, saveto='dataset.png'))
```

so wrt "plt.imread(fname)[...,3]",
 what does it do and how to decompose it to more understandable way.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you spend some more words and code on the actual question? At the moment I do not understand the problem at all. What are you doing? What are the 3 dots? What is it you want to append to? How is the picture you show related to the question? (is it what you want to achieve or is it what you currently have?). Just to say that `plt.imread(fname)[...,3]` is not appending anything, it's just slicing. But I don't know in how far that helps you and you should really ask a specific question to get some help here.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, I have updated the question with edits. I am new to python, the way author has handled slicing , I couldnt decompose it to understand it in better way. suggest a novice way. thanks

Comment: So just to make sure, your code is working fine and you want to understand how it is working, especially wrt to the line `imgs = [plt.imread(fname)[...,:3] for fname in filenames]`. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
imgs = [plt.imread(fname)[...,:3] for fname in filenames]
```

creates a list of 100 images.

`plt.imread(fname)` reads an image and returns a numpy array. You may look at the shape of the array, which should be something like `(n,m,3)` or `(n,m,4)`, where `n` and `m` are whole numbers.

The last axis of dimension 3 or 4 denotes the 3 colorchannels plus possibly a fouth channel which is the alpha (transparency).

The slicing `[...,:3]` is then equivalent to `[:,:,:3]`, which translates in words into "Take all values of the first two dimensions and take the first three values of the third dimension". I.e. you neglect the alpha channel, if present. The reason for doing this is most probably that you want to combine different images here and not all may have an alpha channel. So by neglecting it, you make sure not to run into problems later on.

In this example, you only take jpeg images. Jpeg images do not have an alpha channel and thus you may actually use

```
imgs = [plt.imread(fname) for fname in filenames]
```

which should give you the same result.

Comment: Glad and thanks for details on alpha too.  you could suggest any materials on python and image processing if any.